# Can a templated nested C++ class inherit its enclosing class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, nested-class

This question relates very closely to [Can a nested C++ class inherit its enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485985/can-a-nested-c-class-inherit-its-enclosing-class)

My situation is complicated with templates which seemingly mean that the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485985/can-a-nested-c-class-inherit-its-enclosing-class/1486862#1486862) no longer works.

```
class Animal
{
    template <typename T>
    class Bear : public Animal
    {
        // …
    };

    template <typename T>
    class Giraffe : public Animal
    {
        // …
    };
};

// example usage

struct MyAnimal : Animal::Bear<Animal> { };

MyAnimal a;
```

Can something like this be made to work?

Comment: have you tried doing what they answer in the question you mentioned ? I don't see why using template will change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer works, you just need to know the syntax for it:

```
class Animal
{
    template <typename T>
    class Bear;

    template <typename T>
    class Giraffe;
};

template <typename T>
class Animal::Bear : public Animal
{
    ....
};

template <typename T>
class Animal::Giraffe : public Animal
{
    ....
};
```

Comment: This does not work.  My compiler (VS2010) complains that `Animal::Bear<T>` is not defined.  I am using it later as a base class in another templated class in CRTP style.  `T` is `Animal`.

Comment: Post a minimal example of the problem then. This is the solution to the question you asked.

Comment: @paperjam: This solution compiles just fine in my gcc 4.6.1, and looks right to me.

Comment: Yes, my minimal example compiles with this solution.  I guess I have more dependencies in my real code - am trying to find a way to replicate minimally...

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can. Like suggested in the original question just use forward declaration.

```
#include <iostream>

class Animal
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    class Bear;

    template <typename T>
    class Giraffe;

    int val;
};

template <typename T>
class Animal::Bear : public Animal
{
    public:
    T b_member;

    virtual void print(){
        std::cout << b_member.val << endl;
    }

};

template <typename T>
class Animal::Giraffe : public Animal
{
    public:
    T g_member;

    virtual void print(){
        std::cout << g_member.val << endl;
    }
};

struct BearAnimal : Animal::Bear<Animal> 
{ 
};

struct GiraffeAnimal : Animal::Giraffe <Animal> 
{ 
};


int main()
{
    BearAnimal btest;
    GiraffeAnimal gtest;
    btest.b_member.val = 1;
    gtest.g_member.val = 2;
    btest.print();
    gtest.print();    

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

1
2

Comment: I think you have two different `Bear` classes and two `Giraffe` classes here.  The ones that work aren't nested.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because inheriting requires the full class definition to be available. Since `Bear` and `Giraffe`'s use within `Animal` could affect the definition of Animal you wind up almost with a circular dependency.

Instead, group the related classes in a namespace. I see no reasons why specific animals should be nested within `Animal` at all.

Comment: My real code has no `Animals`.  I'm using CRTP and it is very clean and convenient to have the templated derived class nested inside one of its base classes.